# Sending events (async data) in CANopen with more than 8 bytes of data

Tags: can-bus, canopen

We are developing a typical CANbus networked system with what you could call a controller organizing a number of devices.

The devices needs configuration, which the controller writes (and might also read back) using regular object dictionary items (currently in the manufacturer specific range).

The devices also perform actions (commands) with more than 8 bytes of data and this we solve by having write only items in the device object dictionary and relying on the regular segmentation/de-segmentation of SDO's. (I don't know if this is the *CANopen way* of doing things, but it seems reasonable).

However, the device also produces events (say some sensor data passes a certain threshold) resulting in more than 8 bytes of asynchronous data coming up from the device. PDO's are meant to be used for sending async event data, but it can only contain 8 bytes. The devices could write the data into an object dictionary item on the controller, but this doesn't seem like the CANopen way. Am I right?

The best we've come up with is to send a PDO to the controller, informing the controller that more data are available in the object dictionary on the device.

Anyone with CANopen background that can way in on the best (*CANopen*) way of solving this?

Since I'm repeating 8 bytes a lot, we can safely assume that this network is not running CAN-FD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key of any sensible CAN network design is to consider real-time, data priorities, bus load and data amounts early on. If you find yourself with a chunk of data larger than 8 bytes, then that strongly suggests that something is wrong in this design - it should likely be split in several packages.

Generally, you shouldn't be using SDO for data at all, since they come with overhead. That includes writes to the object dictionary, which also means SDO access. Block transfers etc with SDO are meant for things like bootloaders or one-time configuration, not for live data traffic in operational mode. It can be done, but it is fishy.

You can in theory map data across several PDOs with PDO mapping, but all of this really sounds like an "XY problem" - you are convinced that you need to transmit larger chunks of data and look for a way to do it. But step 1 is to look at the fundamental network data/design and see if you actually need those large chunks or if it makes sense to split them in several. The ideal CANopen design is to have one PDO per type of data, when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so let me clarify and maybe you can help me out. We are putting existing devices on a CANbus (retro-fit) so data packets are sort of fixed. But they are not large (only in terms of CANbus). The longest messages we send are 16 bytes (will fit in two packets).

So is it a better option to use two PDOs (first half, second half) with a timeout for sending both? Also seems fishy to me... but will require only two messages on the bus, vs 8 with the SDO approach (header, ack, 7 bytes, ack, 7 bytes, ack, 2 bytes, ack)

Comment: @VegarWesterlund Yeah it is pretty common to send related data in multiple frames at the same time. If you have for example a controls system with 8 related analog functions, each 16 bit, you'd pack 4 of those in one PDO and the other 4 in another, then send them in sequence. If network priority is correctly designed, they will only get interrupted by more important tasks. The receiver side must be written so that it may accept any of those packages, either at any time or within a time window.

Comment: Please note that it is quite hard to discuss this in general CANopen terms, it all depends on the specifics of the network as whole.

Comment: I understand the difficulty of discussing this in general. But *"it is pretty common to send related data in multiple frames"* is exactly the response I'm looking for. I'd like to avoid having someone with actual CANbus experience coming into the project in two years time and thinking *"why oh why?"*. The network is not going to be congested and the timing constraints are quite loose, so I'm not too concerned about that.